# aws cli, create-device-pool keep occurring error.(I mind rule values should be stringfield already)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-device-farm

I am trying to use AWS cli to upload my apk and test suite to device farm, but stuck in create-device-pool. My cmd is below:

```
aws devicefarm create-device-pool 
--project-arn arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2:398821129922:project:43a44db8-9656-4728-8ebf-96d246ca7d2b
--name terminalpool
--rules '[{"attribute":"ARN","operator":"EQUALS","value":"\"arn:aws:devicefarm:us-west-2::device:3280CD1CC7BE4F37B7209973818F0E12\""}]'
```

Error info:

> An error occurred (InternalFailure) when calling the CreateDevicePool
>   operation (reached max retries: 4):

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out. 
Looks like "EQUALS" operator has some problem. Can you try the "IN" operator.
For more details, please refer this thread
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=216156

Let us know if you still face any issues